# How to disable first select option with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable select option. Which means nothing should be displayed on select tag it should remain blank.

```
<select>
<option value="">ITEM</option>
<option value="">ITEM</option>
<option value="">ITEM</option>
<option value="">ITEM</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("select").disabled = true;
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option>ITEM</option>
  <option>ITEM</option>
  <option>ITEM</option>
  <option>ITEM</option>
</select>
```